# ID Should change dynamically

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.9. I want to give ID dynamically. ID should be change according to letter.

```
$alphas = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');    
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#lettera').click(function() {
            var a = $('#lettera').text();/* alert(a); */
        });
    });
</script>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>
                    <?php
                        foreach($alphas as $letter){
                            echo ($this->Html->tag('a', $letter, ['id' => 'letter'.$letter]));
                        }
                        echo $this->Html->para('bid_val', '');
                    ?>
                <li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add class to every letter and use **this** to get value of clicked one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.letter').click(function() {
        var character = $(this).text();
    });
});


foreach($alphas as $letter){
    echo ($this->Html->tag('a', $letter, ['id' => 'letter'.$letter, 'class' => 'letter']));
}
```